# Unable to instantiate my ViewModel using ViewModelFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I can't bind a ViewModel to my Fragment (using `lateinit`) because I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm creating the ViewModel in my Activity. What am I doing wrong?

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.foo.FooViewModel

Here's the Activity:

```
class FooActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: FooViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo)

        val id = intent.getLongExtra(FOO_ID, 1L)

        val viewModelFactory = FooViewModelFactory(
            id,
            FooDatabase.getInstance(application).fooDao,
            application)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
            this, viewModelFactory).get(FooViewModel::class.java)    
    }
}
```

Exception occurs when the viewModel is instantiated at the time the Fragment attempts to bind it, see commented line of code below:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: FooViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the ViewModel and ViewModelFactory classes:

```
class FooViewModelFactory (
    private val id: Long,
    private val fooDao: FooDao,
    private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(FooViewModel::class.java)) {
             return FooViewModel(
                  id,
                  fooDao,
                  application
             ) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

class FooViewModel(id: Long, fooDao : FooDao, app: Application ): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val _foo = MutableLiveData<Foo>()
    val foo: LiveData<Foo>
        get() = _foo

    // infrastructure needed to get the Foo from the database
    private val _database = fooDao
    private val _fooid = id
    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    // database queries in the IO thread to avoid locking up the UI
    private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.IO)

    init {
        // commenting this out and doing nothing doesn't affect exception in question.
        GlobalScope.launch{ getFoo()}
    }

    private fun getFoo() = ... // code to fetch Foo from database

}
```

Edit: stack trace.

```
2020-05-22 22:10:05.018 8599-8599/com.example.foo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.foo, PID: 8599
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foo/com.example.foo.FooActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.foo.FooViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:269)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.example.foo.BlankFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.example.foo.BlankFragment.onCreateView(BlankFragment.kt:27)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:218)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1183)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:109)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.foo.FooActivity.onCreate(FooActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
2020-05-22 22:10:05.019 8599-8599/com.example.foo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
            ... 40 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare Stack trace is now posted.

Comment: The stack trace indicates that it is not using your factory. I suspect that you need to provide the factory for your `activityViewModels()` call (`activityViewModels { ... }`).

Comment: Post XML of activity

Comment: @CommonsWare Where do you get that from the trace? The documentation indicates that activityViewModels() delegate takes no argument. (Nor should the fragment be the source of knowledge about the data required to initialize the ViewModel)

Comment: "Where do you get that from the trace?" -- the error you cited is coming from `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory`, not your class. "The documentation indicates that activityViewModels() delegate takes no argument" -- [I see an argument](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels).

Comment: @CommonsWare I've got it. The problem was that the `ViewModel by activityViewModels` attempted to create the ViewModel at the time the layout was inflated via the databinding. However, my activity class called `setContentView` before the ViewModelFactory (and viewModel) was declared, thus there was no ViewModel returned at the time the Fragment attempted to perform databinding. I was thrown off by how cryptic the traceback was.

Comment: no, there's a better way, as described by my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `by activityViewModels()` does not get the same factory that would be able to create your viewmodel.

Should be something like this:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: FooViewModel by activityViewModels {
        val application = requireActivity().application
        FooViewModelFactory(
            id,
            FooDatabase.getInstance(application).fooDao,
            application)
    }
```

**EDIT:** Or just provide the factory instance from the Activity. Either way, you're gonna need it to get an instance of `FooViewModel` reliably.

```
class FooActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val viewModelFactory by lazy { 
        FooViewModelFactory(
            intent.getLongExtra(FOO_ID, 1L),
            FooDatabase.getInstance(application).fooDao,
            application)
    }

    private val viewModel: FooViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo)
    }
}
```

And

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: FooViewModel by activityViewModels {
        (requireActivity() as FooActivity).viewModelFactory
    }
```

Comment: That would be true except the Fragment isn't supposed to have knowledge of the information `id`, `fooDao`, `application`, just the `Foo` only as accessed ViewModel. The Activity is responsible for getting these data and sharing them with the Fragments via the shared ViewModel (see my answer). However, please leave your answer here because it will probably be useful to someone else in a different scenario. Thanks!

Comment: That was just the rawest trick to demonstrate creating a factory with the same behavior. Nothing stops you from providing the same instance of the factory, in fact the code will be cleaner. I can add it as an EDIT if you want.

Comment: That's a better principle, but I can't get it working in practice:

`Property delegate must have a 'getValue(BlankFragment, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable.

Lazy<FooViewModel>.getValue(Any?, kProperty<*>) where T = FooViewModel for inline operator fun<T>Lazy<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KPropertyM*>): T defined in kotlin`

I don't know why, it seems like it should work.

Comment: I think I forgot the `: FooViewModel` on the Activity code, care to try again?

Comment: Nope, it wasn't that. (I had already `private val viewModel: FooViewModel by viewModels<FooViewModel> {viewModelFactory})`; the compiler definitely knows it's a `FooViewModel`.)

Comment: Actually I seem to have forgotten the `as FooActivity` although if this fragment intends to be reused, it should define an interface by which it can get the viewmodel factory from its container

Comment: I was having the same issue. I was defining it like so: `private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels { sharedViewModelFactory }`.  I tried OP's way of `lateint` and using `ViewModelProviders` after `setContentView`, and that works, but is deprecated.  I also tried this answer using the factory in my fragment, that worked.  I believe the issue is if it's defined as a parameter, and not used at all in onCreate, then it doesn't get created in time for the fragment.  So I resolved the issue simply by adding the line `sharedViewModel` right after `super.onCreate`, just to exist there

Comment: @phazei you might need to do it before `super.onCreate()` in the activity to make it always available for fragments

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `ViewModel by activityViewModels` delegate attempts to create the ViewModel at the time the layout was inflated via the databinding. However, my activity class called `setContentView` before actually creating the ViewModelFactory (and viewModel), thus there was no ViewModel returned at the time the Fragment attempted to get it.

The solution is to move the call `setContentView` to the end of the `Activity.onCreate()` function.